# C# Cross thread operation not valid after invoked

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I have a problem with Cross-thread operations.

I have the following method

```
 private void UpdateLabel(string text)
    {
        if (this.richTextRxMessage.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.UpdateLabel(text)));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.richTextRxMessage.AppendText(text);
        }
    }
```

and i call it

```
UpdateLabel(richTextRxMessage.Text + szData);
```

I dont understand why i still get this exception

Comment: You cannot access the Text property in the call either.  Make it UpdateLabel(szData) and have UpdateLabel use the Text property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a delegate like

```
  public delegate void UpdateFormText(string text);
```

and change your method like

```
private void UpdateLabel(string text)
{
    if (!this.richTextRxMessage.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.richTextRxMessage.Text=text;

    }
    else
    {
        var s = new UpdateFormText(UpdateLabel);
        Invoke(s, new object[] { text});
    }
}
```